# Load 32-bit greyscale TIFF image in C#

Tags: c#, image

I'm developing a small C# tool that must be able to load a TIFF image, crop the image to a certain size, and save it as a PNG file.

I have large greyscale TIFF images of about 28000x256 pixels with 32-bit bit depth. When I try to process the images with my tool, it just outputs a blank white image.

Also, when I try to open the original TIFF images (not the ones processed with my tool) with the Windows Photo Viewer, it also shows a blank white image. Some other applications, e.g. ImageJ, display the image correctly. What is the problem here?

My code to load the images looks as follows:

```
Image image = Bitmap.FromFile(path.LocalPath);
int width = image.Width;
int height = image.Height;

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
```

Comment: What are you expecting your code to acccomplish? It's not doing anything with the image except taking its dimensions.

Comment: My problem is not the processing of the images, but how to correctly load the images. Currently, I just save the loaded image as a PNG file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that C# (or better said the underlying API) can't handle Greyscale images with a Colordepth greater than 8bit.

I'd suggest using [LibTiff.NET](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/) for Handling TIFF images.
When i faced such an problem, i loaded the TIFF image raw Data into an array

```
using (var inputImage = Tiff.Open(image, "r"))
{
    width = inputImage.GetField(TiffTag.IMAGEWIDTH)[0].ToInt();
    height = inputImage.GetField(TiffTag.IMAGELENGTH)[0].ToInt();
    inputImageData = new byte[width * height * bytePerPixel];
    var offset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputImage.NumberOfStrips(); i++)
    {
        offset += inputImage.ReadRawStrip(i, inputImageData, offset, (int)inputImage.RawStripSize(i));
    }
}
```

The bytes then have to be converted into an array of `uint` (in my case, imagedata was only 16 bit, so i used `ushort`) Remember to take care of Endianness of the data!

```
// has to be done by hand to ensure endiannes is kept correctly.
var outputImageData = new ushort[inputImageData.Length / 2];

for (var i = 0; i < outputImageData.Length; i++)
{
    outputImageData[i] = (ushort)((inputImageData[i * 2 + 1]) + (ushort)(inputImageData[i * 2] << 8));
}
```

You can then manipulate the image using normal Array Operations. I'd suggest you to use normal Array operations and not Lambda-Expressions, as they are much faster. (in My Scenario 100s vs 2s Runtime)

Finally you can save the image using LibTiff again

```
using (var output = Tiff.Open(imageout, "w"))
{
    output.SetField(TiffTag.IMAGEWIDTH, width);
    output.SetField(TiffTag.IMAGELENGTH, height);
    output.SetField(TiffTag.SAMPLESPERPIXEL, 1);
    output.SetField(TiffTag.BITSPERSAMPLE, 16);
    output.SetField(TiffTag.ROWSPERSTRIP, height);
    output.SetField(TiffTag.PHOTOMETRIC, Photometric.MINISBLACK);
    output.SetField(TiffTag.FILLORDER, FillOrder.MSB2LSB);

    // Transform to Byte-Array
    var buffer = new byte[outputImageData.Length * sizeof(ushort)];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(outputImageData, 0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    // Write it to Image
    output.WriteRawStrip(0, buffer, buffer.Length);
}
```

Comment: Can't I just somehow load the 32-bit TIFF image and convert it to 16-bit TIFF? I'm not allowed to use any third-party libraries. I somehow have to get around this problem using the standard libraries.

Comment: That would require loading the TIFF as raw data, thus you'd have to write your own TIFF library. The standard libraries allow you to load 32bit TIFF data but you can't do anything with it. Since LibTiff.Net is under BSD Licencse i'd still consider using it.

Comment: Can't I convert the 32-bit image to 16-bit and then process it using the standard libraries?

Comment: even 16bit is not possible, only 8bit, thus resulting in a huge loss of precission